# How could I implement relocatable data with internal pointers in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, game-development

In game development, it is common to write "baked" assets that are ready to be used by reading their data into memory and using a relocation table to adjust all pointers by the base offset of the buffer used to cache the asset in memory, then directly dereferencing a pointer into that buffer as a particular type. It is similar to relocatable addresses for executable code. This allows for zero-copy reads at runtime, which is significantly faster than parsing the asset into an in-memory format (e.g. parsing JSON to a struct with `serde`). [For example, *Halo: Combat Evolved* loads all .map data in retail builds to the virtual address `0x40440000` and all pointers in the data on disk are already offset by that base address.](https://opencarnage.net/index.php?/topic/3820-map-documentation/&do=findComment&comment=53118)

While this is somewhat straightforward in C and C++, Rust's safety rules present a challenge. Not all bitpatterns are safe for all values, and there are stricter alignment requirements for structures. **Given the following constraints,**

1. All structures represented in the buffer are `repr(C)`, all bitpatterns for non-pointer fields in them are considered valid representations, and may not necessarily have alignment requirements ([ala the `zerocopy` crate's `FromBytes` and `Unaligned` traits](https://docs.rs/zerocopy/0.3.0/zerocopy/trait.FromBytes.html))
2. Magic fields *can* be used and checked to ensure the validity of the referenced structures from a higher struct
3. The pointer to the data is wrapped with `std::pin::Pin` to prevent the data from being moved
4. The *access* of the relocated data does not necessarily have to be safe Rust (e.g. dereferencing unchecked pointers), but the pointers themselves *can* be verified by relocatable offsets accompanying the asset data

How could I implement offset relocation within the loaded asset's buffer, to ensure that the internal pointers of the root structure and all its values are within the bounds of the allocation?

Comment: This is inherently an unsafe operation. Let's assume you load to 0x40440000. Then casting that pointer to a reference to your root data structure would work the same way as in C++, but you'd have to use the unsafe keyword.  Assuming that the data structures were aligned, there would no cost for this, same as in C++. As for unaligned reads - there are functions that will allow you to do this, but they may have a cost, and that would mean you would need to write accessor functions that wrap calls to the unaligned memory.